# Salesforce PHP SOAP API - Unable to get custom WebService working

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

Let me set the scene:

I'm a PHP developer that needs to take info from a web form and send it into a clients Salesforce. At first I though it was as simple as using Web2Lead. However the client has a Salesforce developer in house.

The in house developer has sent me `partner.wsdl` and `CatalystWebservice.wsdl` files along with login details to their sandbox to run all this on. The in house developer has basically said I need to use the SOAP API of Salesforce and once connected and logged in I need to call `->makeContact("FormField1", "FormField2", "etc...");`

So after spending all day trying many things and hitting many problems I have finally hit a wall I cannot climb. Here is my PHP code I have now:

```
<pre>
<?php
define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../soapclient");
$USERNAME = '******@********' ;
$PASSWORD = '******************************' ;
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

try {

    $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
    $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner2.wsdl.xml');
    $loginResult = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

    $location = $mySforceConnection->getLocation();
    $session_ID = $mySforceConnection->getSessionId();

    $client = new SoapClient(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/CatalystWebservice.wsdl.xml');
    $sforce_header = new SoapHeader("http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/CatalystWebservice", "SessionHeader", array( "sessionId" => $session_ID ) );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders( array( $sforce_header ) );

    $client->makeContact("*****", "*****", "Address1", "Address2", "London", "****", "no-one@****", "0123456789", "07891236456", "New Build Homebuy", "This is my question\n\nAnd an other line", "1", "Test");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
</pre>
```

I have starred out sensitive information for here. When I run the above code I get the following output:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: ***********-*** (***********)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /home/******/public_html/********/test/partner.php
    [line:protected] => 23
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
.....
```

And the [CatalystWebservice.wsdl.xml file](http://pastebin.com/04K2Sxp1)

The in house developer has developed something in C# to test his WebService and it works perfectly fine so it must be something I am not doing right. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is there any way you can include a dump of the XML it's generating and sending, compared to the C# version? (For example, with a local proxy like Fiddler) That would give you some idea of where to start looking.

Comment: Another thing to check is whether you're passing in the security token (appended to the password) - if not, you'll need that too.

Comment: I would probably start by using a sniffer to capture your generated XML and compare it with the developer's. The error you're getting is "the bad error" from SFDC - usually a platform-level unhandled exception - that in this case probably does mean that something is fairly messed up, such as non-conformant XML, bad encoding, etc.

Comment: Coincidentally, I posted an example of dumping the raw SOAP request and response from PHP earlier today - https://gist.github.com/1926321 - this might help you debug it.

Comment: I use the Java API so i am not sure how similar they are.  I DO know that i ran into some issues pushing in data I thought was completely valid.  Turns out you need to stuff the data type as it is, not the string equiv.  So if you need to set a date time push the datetime object in as it is, and not the string representation of that date/time...etc  Updating a field that holds a value as a double, push in the value as a double not it's string or even float equiv.  I know PHP Is generally not a strongly typed language though so I don't know how this would reflect on your current issue. :)

Comment: @p.g.l.hall - As the connection is over SSL and network capture is of no use as the data is encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution... I had to make sure I was sending the data as an associative array like so:

```
$response = $client->makeContact
                (
                    array
                    (
                        "sLastName" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['last-name'],
                        "sFirstName" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['first-name'],
                        "sAddress1" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['address-one'],
                        "sAddress2" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['address-two'],
                        "sCity" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['town-city'],
                        "sPostcode" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['post-code'],
                        "sEmail" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['email-address'],
                        "sPhone" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['telephone'],
                        "sMobile" => (string) "",
                        "sEnquiries" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['enquiry'],
                        "sComment" => (string) $wpcf7_data->posted_data['comments'],
                        "sPropertyID" => (string) wpcf7_special_mail_tag_for_post_data( "", "_post_id" ),
                        "sPropertyName" => (string) wpcf7_special_mail_tag_for_post_data( "", "_post_title" ),
                    )
                );
```